# Parse & Facebook Login logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions block not executed

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, facebook-login

I added the facebook login with this method:

```
PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissionsArray, block: { (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if let user = user {
            if user.isNew {
                println("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
            } else {
                println("User logged in through Facebook!");
            }
        } else {
            println("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
        }
    })
```

But the block is never executed. There is no error message.
I followed the Parse Tutorial and did all these steps.
Maybe someone can help?

Answer (score 0):

*I don't think you have implemented the following  in your AppDelegate. Just check  that these methods are defined like this:*

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication )application openURL:(NSURL )url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation 
         { 

              return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication withSession:[PFFacebookUtils session]]; 

          }


-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication )application 
        { 

            [FBAppCall handleDidBecomeActiveWithSession:[PFFacebookUtils session]]; 

        }

-(void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication )application { 

         [[PFFacebookUtils session] close]; 
    }
```

**For Swift, follow the below procedures:-**

```
/ Import this header into your Swift bridge header file
#import <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h>

// AppDelegate.swift
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    Parse.setApplicationId("parseAppId", clientKey:"parseClientKey")
    PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
    return true
}
```

**In your app delegate, add the following handlers:**

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
}
func application(application: UIApplication,
    openURL url: NSURL,
    sourceApplication: String?,
    annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

Reffered from this link:-[here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/2XNfK0KVF9s)

Comment: How to do this with Facebook SDK 4?

Comment: How to do this means?? You just have to define the following methods @FeeBraun

Comment: I was just wondering because FBAppCall doesn't exist anymore it is now FBSDKApplicationDelegate so i was not sure if I need to add the session somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem. My Facebook App was the problem, I changed the app bundle and everything, but it was still referring to the wrong iOS App. So I had to create a new one.